# An issue when looping with while

Tags: c++, qt, loops, while-loop

I have a vector `QVector<float> dist;` where I am keeping Euclidean distances for all dimension that I have. I keep the dimensions as follows:

```
QHash<int, QVector<float> > hash;
```

Where `int` is for keys, and the values are kept again in `QVector<float>`.
The code when I try to fill the `dist` is following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < t; j++)
        {
            while( j <= i)
                j++;
            dist.push_back(qPow((a[i] - hash[i].at(point)), 2) + qPow((a[j] - hash[j].at(point)), 2));
            qDebug() << "Euclidean distance for Dim" << i << "and Dim" << j << " = " << dist[i];
        }
    }
```

The loop calculates everything as supposed, but crashes with a memory error after :

> ASSERT failure in QVector::at "index out of range"...

When I remove `while` loop (the calculations will be WRONG) the application is not crashing any more.

Comment: After the while loop j will be equal to t. I doubt t is a valid index in hash

Comment: What is `a`? What is `point`?

Answer (score 1):

Since i < t and j might be equal i+1 it is possible to generate out of range error while access to a[j]. I.e. sometimes j = t, so you try to access a[t]. It looks incorrect.

May be it will be correct to put

```
while( j < i)
```

instead of

```
while( j <= i)
```

Comment: but what if i=j case also does not fit me?

Comment: Mike, answer on question about 'i=j' depends on your algorithm. Now we can see, that there is a mistake (sometimes j==t, what is wrong). Please specify, how your algorithm must work.

Comment: I have a hash, where keys are dimensions - hash[0]...h[3] - Dim_1...Dim_4, and values are vectors where the coordinates w.r.t dimensions are kept. e.g. - for Dimension 1: h[0] = {1, 2},for Dimension 2: h[1] = {2, 1}, for Dimension 3: h[2] = {1.4, 2.3}, for Dimension 4: h[3] = {0.5, 3}. I want the loop to calculate the Euclidean distance between a[i] elements, where a is also vector predefined with the following code: for(int j = 0; j < t; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            a.push_back(minDim[i] + float(Range[i]*rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))); }}

Comment: Mike, so you don't need to access a[t]. As I understand your problem, you have to correct limirs of first 'for'. Just put "for(int i = 0; i < **t-1**; i++)" in your program.